# iTunes Connect sales and trends not showing

Tags: app-store-connect, ios9

I uploaded an app to the AppStore a few days ago, and the trends tab on the app still shows 5th November when it actually is 26th November. Also, I cannot see my sales and trends data. Any explanations as to why this might be happening? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Then viewing `Sales and Trends` you can set `Custom range` (see image below)

[image]

Also if you upload your app just few days ago there might be still no data. Data of that day usualy will be show only next day about 3pm GMT 0 (+/- few hours)

Comment: @KrishWadhwana if my answer solved your problem you should accept it.